# Refreshes the page when Slider values ​change - Flutter, BloC

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Flutter, I started making a Slider through bloc and writing data to the fireStore, but I ran into a problem - when I change the value in the Slider, the page refreshes and freezes at the *Loading* stage, this is `profile_screen`. How can I fix the problem so that the page is not updated in real time, but only by clicking on the Save button?

**profile_screen**

```
double _currentSliderValue = 1;
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final ProfileBloc infoBloc = context.read<ProfileBloc>();
    ProfileCubit cubit = ProfileCubit.get(context);
    return Scaffold(
        body: Container(
      child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(50),
          child: BlocBuilder<ProfileCubit, ProfileState>(
              builder: (context, state) {
            if (state is ProfileInitial) {
              return const Center(
                child: Text('No Data'),
              );
            }

            if (state is ProfileLoadingState) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator();
            }

            if (state is ProfileLoadedState) {
              return FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
                future: cubit.getInfo(),
                builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasError) {
                    return Text("Something went wrong");
                  }

                  if (snapshot.hasData && !snapshot.data!.exists) {
                    return _userNoInfo(cubit);
                  }

                  if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                    Map<String, dynamic> data =
                        snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                    return _userInfo(data, cubit);
                  }
                  return Text('Loading');
                },
              );
            }
            if (state is ProfileErrorState) {
              return Center(
                child: Text(state.error.toString()),
              );
            }
            return Container();
          })),
    ));
  }

Widget _userInfo(data, ProfileCubit cubit) {
    return Column(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center, children: [
      Form(
          key: _formKeyTwo,
          child: Column(children: [
               Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                  child: Slider(
                      value: _currentSliderValue,
                      max: 100,
                      divisions: 100,
                      label: _currentSliderValue.toString(),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _currentSliderValue = value;
                        });
                      }),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 100),
                _cardData(),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 50.0),
            Center(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    cubit.addAndUpdateInfo(
                        _bisNameContr.text,
                        _bisAddressContr.text,
                        _contactNameContr.text,
                        _contactEmailContr.text,
                        _phoneNumberContr.text,
                        _progNameContr.text,
                        _currentSliderValue.toString());
```

**profile_cubit**

```
class ProfileCubit extends Cubit<ProfileState> {
  final Database _firestoreRepo;

  ProfileCubit(this._firestoreRepo) : super(ProfileInitial()) {
    getInfo();
  }

  static ProfileCubit get(context) => BlocProvider.of(context);

  Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> getInfo() {
    try {
      emit(ProfileLoadingState());
      final Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> infoData =
          _firestoreRepo.getData();
      emit(ProfileLoadedState(infoData));
      return infoData;
    } catch (e) {
      emit(ProfileErrorState(e.toString()));
      throw Exception(e);
    }
  }

  Future<void> addAndUpdateInfo(
    final String bisName,
    final String bisAddress,
    final String contactName,
    final String contactEmail,
    final String phoneNumber,
    final String progName,
    final String progYears,
  ) async {
    await _firestoreRepo.addAndUpdateInfo(bisName, bisAddress, contactName,
        contactEmail, phoneNumber, progName, progYears);
  }
}
```

**cubit_state**

```
abstract class ProfileState extends Equatable {
  const ProfileState();

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class ProfileInitial extends ProfileState {}

class ProfileLoadingState extends ProfileState {}

class ProfileLoadedState extends ProfileState {
  final Future<DocumentSnapshot<Object?>> dataInfo;

  const ProfileLoadedState(this.dataInfo);
}

class ProfileErrorState extends ProfileState {
  final String error;

  const ProfileErrorState(this.error);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [error];
}
```

Comment: Hi, have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build everytime, you can use `buildWhen` which is available inside `BlocBuilder`. if the value is `true`, it will rebuild everytime and if it's false, it will never rebuild. So you can keep a condition over there based on your requirements.

Comment: Please could you show with an example how to use it correctly in my case?